# Google ads banner closed is not showing again

Tags: java, android, admob, adsense

So my problem is with a banner from the google ads SDK for Android. I set up the AdMob and AdSense account and everything is working fine and the banner is showing up in my app. For testing, I closed the banned from the application, pressing the "x" button, saying the ad it was showing was not interesting but it seems like the banner is not loading any other ad even after application restarts after many hours.
For the implementation, I used exactly the code in the google guide for the SDK.

Comment: That shouldn't have any effect on it. Have you tried it on a real device?

Comment: The problem showed on the real device. I closed the banner yesterday morning and now after 26 hours still not showing anything :\ (I am not using emulators)

Comment: Did you use a test ad ID or your ID?

Comment: its my id, the id used for the actual ad, and it was showing the ad until i closed the banner. Now i cant see the banner at all

Comment: That’s strange, do you have a second phone to test it on? Otherwise check your setup again or post the corresponding code and the part of the layout

Comment: So i checked my setup over and over and just today in my google adsense account i have a notification that the account needs to be fully approved. I can see this notification in my mobile google adsense app only but in the browser nothing has changed ever since i saw the first ad appear. This is weird cause first they told me the account was approved, then i could see the ad working and now my account needs a further approvement. Guess i will wait. Is that normal?

Comment: Might be possible that you have to be fully approved, try to finish that part of registration.
And just to clear possible confusion: for apps you use AdMob, AdSense is for Mobile web and web content

Comment: Ok, with further testing i found out the ads are working as expected except for the closed banner: on other devices ads are showing normally, banners and all others, but on the device i closed the banner, instead of another ad showing in the banner i have a transparent space just as if the account was not approved(although it is).

Comment: Then it is just a little buggy with that phone. Re-install the app if you haven't done it already, generate it as a new .apk or try to clear your caches. But if it works in general the need is less urgent I think

Comment: I already reinstalled everything many times(deleting files and cache), it didnt work in the debug version of the app and it doesnt in the release version. At this point i guess its just a bug as you mentioned. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: That's pretty strange, but most important is, that it works on the user's device in the end! You're welcome!